# How can I randomly place background elements on the page?

Tags: html, css, background

I want this kind of background spots in HTML CSS in random places of the body.

[image]

I tried so for this code but did not get the required results...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
body {
    background: #222222;
      background-image:
    /* radial-gradient(#97F1FA 20%, transparent 0),  */
    radial-gradient(#97F1FA 20%, transparent 0);
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  background-position: 0 0, 15px 15px;
}


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by 'certain places' - they look random in the first image you give but have you got definite places where you want them?

Comment: yes, they should be random

Answer (score 2):

If you want runtime randomness, that is on every load the blobs are in different places, you will need Javascript.

As JS isn't one of your tags here's a simpler idea - build in 'random' positions into a background for the body - actually on a pseudo before element on body so you can blur it without affecting the main content.

Obviously you will want to experiment and put in your own positions/number of blobs/blurring etc.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      filter: blur(15px);
      background: #222222;
      background-image: /* radial-gradient(#97F1FA 20%, transparent 0),  */
      radial-gradient(#97F1FA 20%, transparent 0), radial-gradient(#97F1FA 20%, transparent 0), radial-gradient(#97F1FA 20%, transparent 0), radial-gradient(#97F1FA 20%, transparent 0), radial-gradient(#97F1FA 20%, transparent 0), radial-gradient(#97F1FA 20%, transparent 0), radial-gradient(#97F1FA 20%, transparent 0), radial-gradient(#97F1FA 20%, transparent 0);
      background-size: 30px 30px;
      background-size: 50vmin 50vmin;
      background-position: 0 0, 15% 5%, 22% 45%, 45% 56%, 60% 60%, 75% 3%, 87% 88%, 91% 3%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it was really helpful just I am facing one problem that this pattern is not in the background.

Comment: You can check this code :    https://jsfiddle.net/sahibyar/qk9m01aw/1/

Comment: You need to add z-index: -1; to the before pseudo element

Comment: It works.... Thank you so much for your help.